# Jquery add class display block and none

Tags: jquery, css

Hi everyone anyone can help me in my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var circle = $('.circle');
     $(".send a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     $('.wrap').css('display', 'block');

        if (circle.hasClass('bounceInLeft')) {
         circle.removeClass('bounceInLeft').addClass('bounceOutRight');

          }
           else 
          {

         $('.circle').addClass('animated bounceOutRight');
         circle.removeClass('bounceOutRight').addClass('bounceInLeft');
           }

      });

  });
```

When you click `.send a` then `.wrap` will `display:block` . How can i add second click `.send a` then `.wrap` will `display` `none`? I know it should to be like this:

`$('.wrap').css('display', 'none');`  but i don't know where i can write this code...

```
.wrap {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  text-align: center;
  display:none;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.toggle()` to toggle the visibility of the element on each click.

```
$(".send a").on('click', function(e) {
    $('.wrap').toggle();
    // ..
});
```

Alternatively, it would be better to use `.toggleClass()`, and add/remove a class such as `.hide`:

```
.hide {
    display: none; /* You may wish to increase the specificity.. */
}
```

```
$(".send a").on('click', function(e) {
    $('.wrap').toggleClass('hide');
    // ..
});
```

If you are insistent upon manually adding/removing inline CSS, you would just need to use a conditional statement like:

```
$('.wrap').is(':hidden') ? $('.wrap').show() : $('.wrap').hide();
```

Comment: i still add this but when use this then my animation not working on that time can you check this demo from codepen.io [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/bNBXLw)

Answer (score 0):

### [**Demo**](http://goo.gl/z3iUWn)

What I added was a variable that finds out how many times you have clicked the anchor element. 

This way is very simple, and I hope that it works for you. 
Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer but if you can check my DEMO then you can see what is my problem. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/bNBXLw)